# Generics in Java explanation for a vector method thats supposed to accept any type

Tags: java, oop, generics

I am following practices of coding to an interface in java as I learn it. I have a `Function` interface that has an executeFunction() method. But I would like to make this method generic. So the client can pass in a list of Strings, Boolean, Integers, Doubles etc. to run aggregate computation on them.

But I don't have a good grasp of generics so I would like some advice and an explanation of what the design approach I am in the process of coding is actually capable of doing. I'm thinking of having a StatsFunctions and ArithmeticFunctions concrete implementation classes that could be injected in other classes to use their fucntionalit. (Sorta trying the Strategy Pattern).

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.List;

public interface Function {

    public <T> double executeFunction(List<T> vector);

}
```

The Question:

1). How can I use/alter this interface above to make it as generic and dynamic as possible?
    If you could provide some examples of using this, it would be a huge help for my learning.
2). Why can't I do the below? I am getting an error saying: `The operator "+" is undefined for the argument type T.`

```
public class ArithmeticFunctions implements Function {
    @Override
    public <T> double executeFunction(List<T> vector) {
        int retVal = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++) {
            retVal = vector.get(i) + retVal;
        }
        return retVal;
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am not sure you actually need generics here. Can you give example of the client code you would like to use? Just assume the class/methods can do whatever you want

Answer (score 2):

Better yet ::

```
public interface Function<F, T> {
    T apply(F input);
}
```

Use it like this::

```
Function<Integer, Integer> doubleMyInput = new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer apply(Integer input) {
            return input * 2;
        }
};
```

The answer to the second question is not that simple. The error you see is a consequence of type erasure (this is how generics are implemented on the JVM).
Basically, your generic function declaration is equivalent to the following ::

```
public <T extends Object> double executeFunction(List<T> vector);
```

And the Java runtime does not see your type declarations, it only sees Objects.

To understand more clearly, let's assume that we are working in java 1.4, when generics didn't exist. Your interface would then look like this ::

```
public interface MyFunction {

    public double executeFunction(List vector);
}
```

And the implementation ::

```
public class ArithmeticFunction implements MyFunction {

    public double executeFunction(List vector) {
        double retVal = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++) {
            retVal += (((Double)vector.get(i))).doubleValue();
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Note the cast, since there is really no other way to retrieve the value.

You can then do this ::

```
ArithmeticFunction af = new ArithmeticFunction();
// Good
af.executeFunction(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(new Double[] {new Double(1), new Double(2)})));
```

However, this is also possible, and will get you a ClassCastException at runtime ::

```
// Bad !!
af.executeFunction(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"A", "B", "C"})));
```

So to conclude, make a parallel between your implementation (and understand what happens at runtime)::

```
// does not compile
public class ArithmeticFunction implements MyFunction {

    public double executeFunction(List<Integer> vector) {
        int retVal = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++) {
            retVal = vector.get(i) + retVal;
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

and the above-presented example.

Oh, and to fix your problem, you have to do::

```
public interface Function<T> {

    public double executeFunction(List<T> vector);
}
```

I know that maybe some of the concepts presented here are unclear, so your best bet is to get up to speed using a tutorial on generics.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** putting `<T>` on the method means that the actual type of the list will be known when *the method is called*. `<T>` on the interface means that the type of the list is known *when the class is declared*.

This declaration

```
public interface Function {
    public <T> double executeFunction(List<T> vector);
}
```

means to something like:

> The method `executeFunction()` can take in input a list of any type, and calculate a `double` from it.

Who calls this method can legally pass you `List<Double>`, `List<Integer>`, `List<String>` and so on. This is probably not what you want.

If you change the interface declaration like this:

```
public interface Function<T> {
    public double executeFunction(List<T> vector);
}
```

you can declare your class in this way:

```
public class Summation implements Function<Double> {
    public double executeFunction(List<Double> vector) {
        // ...        
    }
}
```

Now you are sure that every element in `vector` is a `Double`, so you can safely sum them up.

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface Function<T> {
  public T executeFunction(List<T> vector);
}
```

Read as:
public interface Function with type T

That is why the function `executeFunction` returns that type T you declared above.

Note that T is always an Object, but Java can handle primitive types (int, double) through automatic boxing.

Comment: This is good, assuming the function will returning a _result_ of the same type as the _inputs_ -- which is not always the case. For example, some functions return a boolean regardless of the input types. Though it's not the exact technical term, perhaps calling it "AggregateFunction" might help indicate what it's used for?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's right to replace `double` by `T` as return type. Note that there will be an `ArithmeticFunctions` class implementation.

Comment: In whatever arithmetic code you might implement, the return value is very likely of the same type as the input. You however can define this as Function<T, R> to define the return value, but at some point it becomes too complex to actually use.

Comment: I need some explanation on generics. For example, why did you use the T in the interface declaration? What if I don't declare it? What if I do? Some knowledge transfer here would help please. I don't care about autoboxing. thanks.

Comment: Generics say that instead of "I write a function using a variable of type double" you say "I write a function using a variable of type T" and later define what type T actually is. It is kind of a variable for a Type. You are allowed to give those variables any name you want (T is the most common though) and can use that placeholder in any place where you would normally write a variable type. During runtime the JIT then replaces the placeholder with the actual type to be used.

Comment: Okay. Then why can't I do this: `public class ArithmeticFunctions implements Function {

 @Override
 public <T> double executeFunction(List<T> vector) {
  int retVal = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++) {
   retVal = vector.get(i) + retVal;
  }
  return retVal;
 }

}` I formatted this above in the question for your easy viewing